# Coderush - Shortcut for Generic ICollection

Tags: coderush

Is there a shortcut in Coderush to generate code for an ICollection?

Answer (score 0):

CodeRush can certainly help with all sorts of code generation.

If you could be a little more specific with your question, I will refine this answer and show you what you need.

Which version of Studio (and hence .Net) are you using?

What sort of code ywould you like to see generated?

I ask because ICollection implies an interface but not what processes should back it. there are many ways in which you might choose to do this.

CodeRush cannot guess but if you have some more clues I might be able to help